# How do I change ime keyboard focus key?

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I've added a qwerty keyboard to my application and when the user focus to the search field, it opens the keyboard and he still needs to hit right key to focus to the keyboard. Keyboard is below the fields, so the right key is not intuitive!

I would like to know how to change that key?

Or where can I find the name of the function that does this thing?

Thanks

Edit - Code that I used:

```
var pluginAPI = new Common.API.Plugin();
var ime;
var Main = {};

Main.onLoad = function(){
    pluginAPI.registIMEKey();
    ime = new IMEShell('search', Main.imeReady, 'en');
};

Main.imeReady = function(){
    // focus callbacks
    ime.setKeyFunc(tvKey.KEY_UP, function(keyCode) { return false; } );
    ime.setKeyFunc(tvKey.KEY_DOWN, function(keyCode) { return false; } );
    ime.setKeyFunc(tvKey.KEY_RETURN, function(keyCode) { widgetAPI.sendReturnEvent(); return false; } );
    ime.setKeyFunc(tvKey.KEY_EXIT, function(keyCode) { widgetAPI.sendExitEvent(); return false; } );

    // install status callbacks
    ime.setKeypadPos(410, 80);
    ime.setWordBoxPos(18, 6);
    ime.setEnterFunc(function(){});//stuffs
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
document.getElementById("search").focus();
```

Update, Some docs said you can simulate key event on IME using this http://samsungdforum.com/Guide/ref00011/deviceapi_ime_inputkey.html

```
IMEPlugin.InputKey(82);
```

Comment: I'm already doing this, when I focus to the field the keyboard appears, but I still need to hit right key on remote control to really focus on the first key! :/